# Keeping blank values for int columns in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am loading csv files to sql server table. EmpNo Ename ProdID Sales Value Int Varchar Int Int Float

But I am getting ProdID,Sales,Amount Values as 0 for blanks.But want to keep them as blank. I am using this code for keeping nulls.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,names=file_titles,low_memory=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.fillna(value=' ')
```

**Source Data**

```
EmpNo   Ename   ProdID  Sales   Amount
1   E1      10  120.00
2   E2  1   2   100.00
3   E3          
4   E4  3   3   353.00
5   E5      6   443.00
6   E6  4   8   533.00
```

Expected Output

```
EmpNo   Ename   ProdID  Sales   Amount
1   E1  0   10  120.00
2   E2  1   2   100.00
3   E3  0   0   0.00
4   E4  3   3   353.00
5   E5  0   6   443.00
6   E6  4   8   533.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
  `df=df.where(df[['Ename','ProdID','Sales']].eq(' '),0)`

Comment: I confused. How to load the data as it is like if value is blank. It must must be blank likebelow or same source data.EmpNo   Ename   ProdID  Sales   Amount
1   E1      10  120.00
2   E2  1   2   100.00
3   E3          
4   E4  3   3   353.00
5   E5      6   443.00
6   E6  4   8   533.00

Comment: I confused. How to load source data is it is. if value is blank, it must be blank.Please help me.

Comment: what command are you using to import to sql? it could be fail. I need see it