# How to load blank values as blank for CSV value measures/int in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am loading csv files to sql server table. EmpNo Ename ProdID Sales Value Int Varchar Int Int Float

But I am getting ProdID,Sales,Amount Values as 0 for blanks.But want to keep them as blank. I am using this code for keeping nulls.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None,names=file_titles,low_memory=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df = df.fillna(value=' ')
```

**Source Data**

```
EmpNo   Ename   ProdID  Sales   Amount
1   E1      10  120.00
2   E2  1   2   100.00
3   E3          
4   E4  3   3   353.00
5   E5      6   443.00
6   E6  4   8   533.00
```

Expected Output

```
  EmpNo Ename   ProdID  Sales   Amount
1   E1      10  120.00
2   E2  1   2   100.00
3   E3          
4   E4  3   3   353.00
5   E5      6   443.00
6   E6  4   8   533.00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping blank values for int columns in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666246/keeping-blank-values-for-int-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: possible? it's the same person and question :D

Comment: HI Derek, This is not duplicate. This is other query. Please help me.Thank you. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', keep_default_na=False)
```

maintains blank cells as blank

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> df
   1    2    3
0  1  NaN    q
1  2  NaN    q
2  3    w  NaN
3  4    w    q
```

---

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Workbook2.csv',keep_default_na=False)
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  1     q
1  2     q
2  3  w   
3  4  w  q
```